# Does the AWS CloudWatch Agent installed on-prem buffer metrics/logs data in case of connection loss?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I cannot understand if the CloudWatch Agent installed on-prem has some sort of spooler to temporarily store metrics/logs data in case of provisional loss of connection. I could not find it anywhere in the documentation, and I cannot really perform a realistic test to see in first person if that works.

Thanks!